# How to generate an animated tie dye-like gradient as a texture?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I'm trying to generate an animated texture that looks something like the "LUMP CANDY" text in the logo of this image:

[image]

I've found some animated gradient solutions here, but I haven't been able to generate a texture with some of the default procedural texture options in Blender that looks quite like the image. Any ideas?

EDIT: I ended up adapting one of the textures from [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/my-100-free-cycles-procedural-textures-blend-files-and-or-settings-included/1113432/8)—the one in "Cycles Procedural Texture Pack # 5" at the top left. This was the result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use the *Wave Texture* node, then play with its *Distortion* value and with parameters of the *Mapping* node:

[image]